# Build latest Angular CLI app but uses local previous version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have been using Angular since version 2.  Angular 14 is out, so I’m attempting to fully embrace the new version and test any changes.  I have created a simple reference application to assist in the process.  I both upgrade the reference application and rebuild it anew.

To build the reference application anew, I installed version 14 globally as follows:

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

I try to create the new application as follows:

`ng new demo-mg14 --routing --skip-git`

It comes back with the following:

> Your global Angular CLI version (14.0.3) is greater than your local version (13.3.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.

How can I create a new Angular 14 application without having to convert it?

Comment: Are you trying to start a new angular project in an another angular project directory ?!

Comment: This is being created in the "ng" folder.  Other application have been made in the "ng" folder via the `ng new` cli command.  The above demo-mg14 application is not imbedded in another Angular application.  This is all based around a process of fully embracing a new Angular version and testing any changes.  I am trying to create a reference application.

Comment: I was able to create demo-mg14 application in another directory and then move it to the NG folder.  The version 13 upgraded ot 14 just fine, but I am still challenged with the `ng new` reference application.

Comment: Somehow I had a node_modules folder that contain a version 13 CLI in my Angular projects folder.  So, in essence Tawfiek asked the correct question.  Thanks.